# bootfaces with icefaces, display none b:tab, in b:tabview

Tags: jsf, tabview, bootsfaces

About the using of b:tabView of Bootfaces 1.0.1, it  works in the showcase but no in my template, when I click in a tab it dessapears. Thanks some help here. I am using also Icefaces 3.3.0

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
                <!DOCTYPE ...>
                <html ...>
                    <h:head>
                    </h:head>
                    <h:body>
                        <ui:composition template="../plantillas/principal.xhtml">
                            <ui:define name="content">

 <b:panel id="uno" title="Pacientes"  collapsible="false"       look="primary"  
             rendered="#{!pacientes.formulario.mostrar}">
        <b:panel id="diez" title="Términos de Búsqueda"  collapsible="false"   look="primary" class="fuenterabs">
            <b:panelGrid colSpans="6,6" size="md">  
                <b:row>
                    <b:label  text="Grupo sanguineo:" class="fuenterabs" col-md="12" span="4" />
                    <ice:selectOneMenu class="form-control bf-no-message has-success" value="#{pacientes.tiposangreb}"  partialSubmit="true" >
                        <f:selectItems value="#{tablaDeCodigos.comboTipoSangre}" />
                    </ice:selectOneMenu>
                </b:row>
            </b:panelGrid> 
        </b:panel>
        <ace:menuBar autoSubmenuDisplay="true" >
            <ace:menuItem  class="btn   btn-primary fa fa-file-o   bicep" value="Nuevo"  action="#{pacientes.nuevo()}"/>
            <ace:menuItem class="btn btn-info fa fa-search bicep" value="Buscar"  action="#{pacientes.buscar()}"/>
        </ace:menuBar>
        <ace:messages   />
    </b:panel>

                                <b:panel id="tres" title="Centro"  collapsible="false" >

                                         <b:tabView pills="true" contentStyle="border: 1px solid #ddd;padding:10px">
                                        <b:tab title="JSF markup">

                                        </b:tab>
                                        <b:tab title="second tab">
                                            Put some text here.
                                        </b:tab>
                                    </b:tabView>
                                </b:panel>
                            </ui:define>
                        </ui:composition>

                    </h:body>
                </html>
```

Comment: I'm not the one who down-voted the question, but it is unclear what the question is asking. You may get better feedback if you re-word your question.

Comment: @BrandonMinnick Thanks! I'm sure this kind of feedback helps people to learn how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of at least two different reasons:

- ICEfaces. BootsFaces is officially **not** compatible with ICEfaces. I know some people managed to get this combination of frameworks up and running, but it's difficult. Among other things, the automatic AJAX feature of ICEfaces doesn't bode well with BootsFaces. We work hard to produce as clean HTML code as possible, but ICEfaces requires immaculate, flawless HTML code. Last time I checked we didn't generate code ICEfaces could cope with.
- Your template. You didn't show it, so it can contain any code.

I suggest you try to simplify the code and see when the error vanishes:

- Get rid of the pill tabs. I don't think they cause the problem, but they are a deviation from the standard, so it's a good idea to check this, just in case.
- Put your snippet on a page without your template.
- Remove ICEfaces from your application. To do so, you probably need to create a new project or a copy of the project which you can simplify radically.

Oh, and check the JavaScript console (the F12 tool, or CMD+ALT+I on OSX). Maybe you spot an error message there.

Once you've figured out what's the problem, please report back, so other developers can benefit from your experience. Thanks in advance! and: ¡Buena suerte!

Comment: Well, I tried use only Panels, Grid System and Buttons + Widgets Iof Icefaces (ace:table, ace:fileEntry) and apparently it works! Of course ace:fileEntry have a listener, I had the problem the b:combutton of Bootfaces does a submit of the page and the listener has executed, but I have used ajax="true" update="@form" in the bottom and seems works. I am not a master and I learning, but You think I am taking the worst wrong way thinking only take Panels and Grid system? Thanks in advance Friend! –

Comment: If it works, it works :). There's nothing wrong with picking components from each framework. It's just that I didn't have much luck with using my complex examples in an ICEfaces environment. As long as you keep in mind that some of our components may generate HTML code browsers can parse, but ICEfaces can't, everything's fine.